# Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function used google maps with leaflet js

Tags: google-maps

I have two markers at the same position (the longitude and latitude)

So to resolve this , i have tried to use markercluster Option .

I was following this fiddle to implement markercluster feature into my code

http://jsfiddle.net/dP9aG/96/

This is my fiddle

http://jsfiddle.net/dP9aG/101/

But when i tried to use leaflet with my code

i am getting the following error in my console

Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function

This is my code

```
    var map;
    var markers = new L.MarkerClusterGroup();
    initmap();

    function initmap() {
        map = new L.Map('map');
        var googleLayer = new L.Google('ROADMAP');
        map.addLayer(googleLayer);
        drawTestLine();
    };

    function drawTestLine() {
        var lat = 51;
        var long = 7;
        for (var i = 0; i < 50; i++) {
            var myMarker = new L.Marker(new L.LatLng(lat, long), 3);
            myMarker.on('click', function(e) {
                popup = new L.Popup();
                popup.setLatLng(this.getLatLng());
                var popuptxt = "Hello!";
                alert("I am the click function");
                popup.setContent(popuptxt);
                map.openPopup(popup);
            });
            markers.addLayer(myMarker);
            lat = lat + 0.0001;
            long = long + 0.0001;
        }
        map.addLayer(markers);
    };
```

Could you please let me know how to resolve this , thanks

http://jsfiddle.net/dP9aG/101/

Answer (score 0):

You did not include the Google maps script in your header. The example you are referring to is using openstreetmaps and there the map script is loaded in the js.

[Here](http://jsfiddle.net/dP9aG/102/)'s the updated fiddle. I could get the map loaded fine.

```html
<script src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?v=3.2&sensor=false"></script>
<script src="http://matchingnotes.com/javascripts/leaflet-google.js"></script>
```